# Is calling sizeof (*s.begin()) safe?

Tags: c++, sizeof

while doing some TMP :) :(
I ended up needing the size of the element that STL container holds. 
I know that usually deref an container.begin() iterator is bad without checking if container isnt empty, but from what I know sizeof is compiletime macro so I *guess* it is safe. 
Am I right?

code snippet is :

```
    for(auto it = t.begin(); it!= t.end(); ++it)
    {
        char* cp = (char*)(&(*it));
        for (size_t i =0 ; i < sizeof *t.begin();++i)
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's safe, but realize that you can get at the types stored in a container via the `key_type`, `mapped_type` and/or `value_type` `typedef` members.

E.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    int bla;
    double quuxly;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<Foo> foovector;
    std::cout << "sizeof(Foo) == " << sizeof(foovector::value_type) << "\n";
}
```

[`sizeof` is not a *macro*, btw. It's an operator built into the language itself, like `++` or `|=`.]

Answer (score 6):

It *is* safe, since the expression inside `sizeof(...)` is not evaluated. For `sizeof` (and similarily `decltype`, `typeid` and other similar constructs) only the *type* matters. The value is of no interest (how could a value be of interest *at compile time*?), which is why there's no need to evaluate the expression. Even dereferencing a null pointer is safe inside an unevaluated context.

Comment: +1 for providing the **reason** why it is allowed (even in the case where the container is empty).